# C# editing a fillable form

Tags: c#, pdf

My Task is to add User name to a fillable pdf (on the margin, not field) using C#. I tried to add a Text Annotation using a lot of Third Party dll like  iTextSharp, spire.pdf....

However, whenever I add the text on the fillable pdf and save it, the fillable Fields disappear. Does anyone know how to complete this Task? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of form does your PDF have? (AcroForm? XFA? Hybrid?) Is there a usage rights signature, i.e. is the document Reader enabled? Do you apply your changes in append mode, i.e. as incremental update?

Comment: Please provide more detail. What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: I tried Aspose, Bytecont, FoxIt, iTextSharp, Spire.pdf

Comment: At least with iTextSharp, you may need to "Flatten" the file. See: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-flattening-form

Comment: @Alex if you want help, you had better start answering clarification requests. Out of five such requests you responded to only one and that in a very shallow manner only.

Answer (score 0):

seems to you use broken pdf file because of it is simple task.
I don't know how looks your code for tools you have tried. I use Apitron PDF Kit. Anyway I think it will look similarly for all tools.
Please see the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout;
using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout.Content;
using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout.PageProperties;
using Apitron.PDF.Kit.Interactive.Annotations;
using Apitron.PDF.Kit.Interactive.Forms;

    public void TestAcroForm_TextBlock()
    {
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream("filename.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument())
            {
                Page page = document.Pages[0];

                TextField textField = new TextField("UserName", "This is user name");
                TextFieldView annotation = new TextFieldView(textField, new Boundary(100, 100, 300, 130));

                document.AcroForm.Fields.Add(textField);
                page.Annotations.Add(annotation);
                using (Stream outStream = new FileStream("filename_out.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    document.Save(outStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```